# why doesn't splat work directly with command in powershell?

Tags: powershell, splat

Why does the following work:

```
Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem
```

And this works also:

```
$params = @{class='Win32_OperatingSystem'}
Get-WmiObject @params
```

But this doesn't work:

```
Get-WmiObject @{class='Win32_OperatingSystem'}
```

ERROR:

```
Get-WmiObject : Invalid query "select * from System.Collections.Hashtable"
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-WmiObject @{class='Win32_OperatingSystem'}
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

Comment: Because you are not splatting, but passing `Hashtable` as position argument.

Comment: seems like an obvious shortcut that the powershell developers overlooked

Comment: With that "shortcut" in place: how would you distinguish between splatting and passing a hashtable as a positional parameter?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, wouldn't `@@{...}` be perfect for this? It sounds logical: direct splatting of hashtable. Also the `@@` sequence is currently an unrecognized token in my (limited) tests. Not sure if it's used in any other contexts.

Comment: @efotinis That might work, although I don't feel a very pressing need for it. But feel free to [open an issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell).

Answer (score 6):

Splatting is a method of passing a collection of parameter values to a command as unit. Windows PowerShell associates each value in the collection with a command parameter. Splatted parameter values are stored in named splatting variables, which look like standard variables, but begin with an At symbol (@) instead of a dollar sign ($). The At symbol tells Windows PowerShell that you are passing a collection of values, instead of a single value.

If you do not store it into a variable, it is not splatting, it is a simple hashtable, which is passed as a positional argument into the command.

**Reference**

[About splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-5.1)